# Unable to read cookies in page.tpl.php

Tags: 7, cookies

I am trying to execute the following in page.tpl.php.

```
setcookie('front_page_survey','yes', time() + (86400 * 365), "/"); 
echo $_COOKIE['front_page_survey'] .'cookie' ;
```

`setcookie()` works as intended, but when I try to read it, nothing get printed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should never have logic like that in a template file - always put it in a preprocess function. Try that and see if it fixes the problem, could well be cache related

Comment: same effect. still not able to get the value!

Comment: Is this a single page load?

Comment: did you clear/flush the cache?

Comment: yes! one reason it might be i am using varnish

Comment: @cilefen yes Though cookies show up on browser but unable to get in in page.tpl.php or template.php

Comment: @Clive i put the same code in  hook preprocess page in template.php but it still doesnt show the value of cookie